# Having trouble understanding classes c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
class myClass
{
private:
    struct myStruct
    {
        int width = 0;
    };
public:
        myClass();
        void changeValue();
};

myClass::myClass()
{
    myStruct aStruct;
    aStruct.width = 24;
}

void myClass::changeValue()
{
    aStruct.width = 23;
}
```

I made the simple code above in order to test classes. In the member function changeValue i get the error saying that aStruct is not defined. But i don't really understand why it says it's undefined. Previously when i worked with classes this kind of code has worked fine. The difference between then and now is that in the class constructor i used pointers. So does this type of code only work for pointers and not for structs?

The reason i want this to work is it would be really usefull to have this "global" object that belongs to the class that is a struct.

Comment: `In the member function changeValue i get the error saying that aStruct is not defined.` Yeah, because it is not defined. You need to move `myStruct aStruct;` inside your class and not inside the constructor.

Comment: In the constructor, you create a temporary variable which gets destroyed as soon as you leave the constructor.

Comment: @dimChtz yes this is exactly what i wanted. what do you call when you initiate an object like that? is it just a local object to the class?

Comment: @JimmyJoe In that case `aStruct` is just a member of `myClass`.

Comment: you need some kind of book on C++. Note, C book won't cut it for basics even, they don't match in syntax  and semantics for 100%. C++ is dangerously abstract language, you can't figure it just by looking at the form of code. Worse are only LUA and Rust, perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trouble with "understanding classes". You should go back and understand what "scope" is, which is one of basic concept of C++ language.

```
 myStruct aStruct;
```

belongs to scope of member function `myClass::myClass()` and ceases to exist when execution of that function ends. This is completely different scope, aStruct variable doesn't exist there.

```
void myClass::changeValue() 
{
     aStruct.width = 23; // aStruct doesn't exist in any available scope 
}
```

Now about declarations:

```
class myClass
{
private:
    struct myStruct
    {
        int width = 0;
    };
```

This code doesn't declare a struct storage inside of class`myClass`. It declares ***member type*** `myStruct` (which is a class-type) inside of class `myClass`.

(Be wary of this name convention, it's very confusing. It's recommended to use capitalization like that only for members. Classes recommended to be all lower case or starting with capital letter.)

```
class myClass
{
private:
    struct myStruct
    {
        int width = 0;
    };

    myStruct aStruct; // myClass got field aStruct

public:
    myClass() : aStruct {24} {}
    void changeValue();
};
```

`aStruct` here belongs to the private part of scope of class, which is available for all members of this class.  `myStruct` is also declared as private so can't be used outside of class, be that in child class or just in outer scope.

```
myClass() : aStruct {24} {}
```

This is a non-trivial (user-defined) constructor with initializer list. `aStruct` is field of this class, so it can be initialized with a value like this. It is different from this form

```
myClass() 
{
   aStruct.width = 24;
}
```

In latter case, `aStruct` would be initialized *first* (with 0 in width field, as you had  instructed) and its constructor will be called, then `myClass`s  constructor would change value of its field to 24.

Comment: alright, maybe i misunderstood the constructor then. because i always assumed it creates an object that is local to the class and will exist in every function that belongs to that class.

Comment: @JimmyJoe no,class is just a type of storage, nothing special. like that. consider member functions (methods) of class as a function pointers inside of struct. there is no difference between struct and class in C++, they are both class-types. Object in C++ is a storage that contains one element or an array of _any_ type.  Constructor exist always, when you declare your own, you define what happens when storage begins to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Before your question gets busted, you got to understand that everything in `{}` is scoped inside those braces, thus your problem here is that you have:

```
myStruct aStruct;
```

inside constructor. So `aStruct` is local variable to the constructor. In order to fix your code move it just below `struct` definition.

```
class myClass
{
private:
    struct myStruct
    {
        int width = 0;
    };

    // MOVE IT HERE
    myStruct aStruct;
public:
    myClass();
    void changeValue();
};

myClass::myClass()
{
    aStruct.width = 24;
}

void myClass::changeValue()
{
    aStruct.width = 23;
}
```

Now all member functions can access `aStruct`.